# Recording audio output

Tags: audio, alsa, recording

I've been following these instructions for recording the output of a program I wrote (that uses rtaudio to synthesize music) http://jordilin.wordpress.com/2006/07/28/howto-recording-audio-from-the-command-line/

However, when I try to use arecord I just record the microphone, not the output of my program.

Using arecord -l to list capture devices I see :

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC269VB Analog [ALC269VB Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Does this look like it's giving me the option to record the output of another program? And if so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I've found to work for recording PulseAudio output.
You can record multiple processes and hear what's being recorded at the same time.

You'll need Pulse Audio volume control ([pavucontrol](http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol/)) and some software such as [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) to record the audio.

- Run `pavucontrol`.
- Go to the `Input Devices` tab on `pavucontrol` and mute all the input devices, unless you want to record from your microphone at the same time.
- Run `audacity` or another recording program. In Audacity you can monitor the output without recording, which is handy since you need to do this for PulseAudio to recognize it. I found capturing ALSA and default to work just fine.
- Go to the `Recording` tab on pavucontrol and set your recording software to "ALSA Capture *from* Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Software". If nothing shows up in the "Recording" tab, then make sure your capture application is actually recording.
- Go to the `Playback` tab and adjust the levels for each process to your liking. You can also adjust the levels from your speakers or headphones in the "Output Devices" tab.
- Record, edit, export, etc.
- Don't forget to unmute your `Input Devices` if you did that earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I get just about same output from `arecord -l`.  I've used `audacity` to record a song from a website (yes, I tried to buy the song from the site, but...).  Need to get the right adjustment of muting the microphone (if possible) and then cleaning up any static/background noise.  So for you, I would start `audacity`, start your program, set to record to a new project and then perform the functionality the you want to record.

Comment: I tried Audacity too. But same problem. I'm not recording any of the output of my program at all. I'm just getting the microphone.

Comment: Try this: from the mixer, go to capture and ensure that microphone's volume is down and the others are up.

Comment: Nothing I'm afraid. I just don't think that ALSA (or PulseAudio not quite sure which is running the show) knows about the program as a potential input source. Alsamixer doesn't have a "mix" as an input option. Pavucontrol shows me a "Monitor of Internal Audio Analogue Stereo" and I've set that to 100% but it has no effect.