# Programmatically redirect audio output of specific program to file

Tags: debian, command-line, audio, recording

I would like to redirect the audio output of a program to file, on the command line, like in

```
$ redirect-wrapper file.wav my-program
```

so that

- I don't hear the output of the program, i.e. the output should *only* go to the file
- I don't record anything besides the program, i.e. only *this specific* program is redirected to the file
- the rest of the audio system is left completely undisturbed, no configuration options changed back and forth or something like that

Is there a way to do this? [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27865/recording-audio-output) related question does *not* help, I need a command line solution, no "click there, then there". [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/609292/different-applications-different-sound-output-devices) is probably also related, but also relies on the graphical application pavucontrol. I found a terminal alternative to pavucontrol, pacmd.

But this still only makes the following compromise possible:

1. Get the default sink and save what it was. How? Probably grepping through `pacmd list-sinks`
2. Set default sink to the snd-aloop sink with `pacmd set-default-sink`.
3. Record from that sink.
4. Launch application
5. Wait until the application opened its sink input: `pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep name-of-my-program` if this finds something, the input is open.
6. Change the default back to what it was with `pacmd set-default-sink` .
7. Stop recording once the application closes.

But this still changes the default sink for a timespan of up to a couple of minutes (the sink input isn't usually opened until the program is actually playing sounds which doesn't need to be right after launch). I implemented this compromise; [Github](https://github.com/TT44bb/sound-recording-wrapper.sh/tree/master).

Still searching for non-compromising answers.

Comment: This could help: http://www.swview.org/node/213 He is temporarily changing `~/.asoundrc`. Maybe you can avoid this somehow.

Comment: @rudimeier That is globally setting the default output device. No matter whether from ~/.asoundrc or in an other way, it will always mess the rest of the audio system up.

Comment: No idea, but I think you're on the right track. The output of `pacmd list` shows what sources and sinks are attached to particular programs, so there may be a way to change them. Try asking on the pulseaudio list at https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/pulseaudio-discuss The maintainers/developers are there and are quite helpful.

Comment: @Joe Reassigning sinks is possible with pacmd, yes, but because they are only allocated when audio actually starts playing (at least for some programs; Firefox), that means I would need to search for them in a tight loop and would possibly miss the first 0.5s or so of the audio. Thanks for the tip about the mailing list. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm so looking at the pulseaudio documentation.

`man pulseaudio`

We have the following environment variables

```
   $PULSE_SERVER: the server string specifying the server to connect to when a client asks for a sound server connection  and  doesn't  explicitly  ask  for  a  specific
   server.  The server string is a list of server addresses separated by whitespace which are tried in turn. A server address consists of an optional address type speci‐
   fier (unix:, tcp:, tcp4:, tcp6:), followed by a path or host address. A host address may include an optional port number. A server address may be prefixed by a string
   enclosed in {}. In this case the following server address is ignored unless the prefix string equals the local hostname or the machine id (/etc/machine-id).

   $PULSE_SINK: the symbolic name of the sink to connect to when a client creates a playback stream and doesn't explicitly ask for a specific sink.
```

This should hopefully allow you to complete replace the pulseaudio sink, and if this isn't enough run our own single use pulseaudio server.

Referring to this page (https://askubuntu.com/questions/60837/record-a-programs-output-with-pulseaudio), we find out about the `parec`/`pacat` command (they are aliases) which can record from and write to sinks and streams.

Putting this together we have the following wrapper (which I haven't actually run - though I've successful got this method to work on an ad-hoc basis)

```
sink_name="sink-$(date +%s)"
pacat $sink_name.monitor 
parec -d steam.monitor | oggenc -b 192 -o /tmp/steam.ogg --raw - &
pid=$!
PULSE_SINK=$sink_name "$@"
kill $pid
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid. Thanks. ^^ Eventually I'll learn to read the documentation first.

Comment: So how do I use this script? Put it in a file (call it `redirect-wrapper.sh`) and run `redirect-wrapper.sh file.wav my-program`? @Nobody

Comment: @MinaMichael You would need to understand it to use it an adapt it to your needs. For starters, line 3 needs to have $sink_name.monitor instead of steam.monitor. The output file is hardcoded to /tmp/steam.ogg in line 3.