# Using PulseAudio to pipe audio from multiple applications into separate files in parallel

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, pulseaudio, recording

I would like to redirect the audio output of multiple applications to multiple files in parallel on Ubuntu. For example, if I have two instances of Chrome running in the background at the same time, I would like to be able to redirect their audio outputs into two separate files. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325874) answer got me close, as I can record from a single instance (call it instance A) at a time. However, as soon as I start recording from a second instance (instance B), that second instance seems to grab both its audio stream and the audio stream from the first. The result is two audio files, but the file `instance_a_output.ogg` will cut to silence at the time corresponding to when the command starting instance B is run. Additionally, `instance_b_output.ogg` will have the audio from both the A and B streams.

I think my problem might be a 'native sink input', as described in the "Connect a playback application to a file" section of [this](https://gavv.github.io/articles/pulseaudio-under-the-hood/) website.

This is my wrapper function (like in the answer I mentioned above):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Example invocation:
# ./wrapper.sh output_name mpg123 example.mp3

my_sink_name="sink-$(date +%s)"
module=`pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=$my_sink_name`
parec -d $my_sink_name.monitor | oggenc -Q -b 192 -o ~/audio/$1.ogg --raw - &
pid=$!
(export PULSE_SINK=$my_sink_name; ${@:2})
pactl unload-module $module
kill $pid
```

For completeness, this is the python script I'm using to call the wrapper, but I don't think the problem is there.

```py
import subprocess
import time

command1 = ["/home/myname/audio/wrapper.sh", "test{}".format(1), "mpg123", "-q", "example.mp3"]
command2 = ["/home/myname/audio/wrapper.sh", "test{}".format(2), "mpg123", "-q", "example.mp3"]

subprocess.Popen(command1)
time.sleep(3)
subprocess.Popen(command2)
```

Any ideas about how to resolve this issue?